# jquery datatable in nested repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a repeater inside a repeater and I initialize both as datatable and the nested one just won't work, it shows the elements on the 1st row but nothing works, paging or filter and on other rows they don't even the paging, filter etc...

here is the source:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptArquivo" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptArquivo_ItemDataBound">
                    <headertemplate>
                    <table id="tblArquivo" class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                                <th>Armazem</th>
                                <th>Data</th>                                  
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                </headertemplate>
                    <itemtemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                              <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="../../Images/Collapse/plus.png" width="20" />
                                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlArquivoLocalizacoes" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptArquivoLocalizacoes" runat="server">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <table id="tblArquivoLocalizacoes" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>ID</th>
                                                            <th>Localização</th>
                                                            <th>Etq. Por Inventariar</th>
                                                            <th>Etq. Inventariadas</th>
                                                            <th>Precisão</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblIdlocalizacao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdArquivoLocalizacao") %>' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblLocalizacao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Localizacao") %>' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblEtiquetasPorInventariar" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EtiquetasPorInventariar") %>' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblEtiquetasInventariadas" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EtiquetasInventariadas") %>' />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPrecisao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Precisao") %>' />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                </table>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblIdArquivo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdArquivo") %>' />
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblColaborador" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Nome") %>' />
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblArmazem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Armazem") %>' />
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblData" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Data") %>' />
                        </td>                            
                    </tr>
                </itemtemplate>
                    <footertemplate>
                    </table>
                </footertemplate>
                </asp:Repeater> ~
```

and here I initialize tables:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblArquivo').DataTable()
    $('#tblArquivoLocalizacoes').DataTable()
});
```

How can i solve this problem so that I can show every row on the nested repeater with jquery?

**EDIT**

I managed to solve the part to show the jquery datatable elements by changing the initializer to a class instead an identifier

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblArquivo').DataTable()
    $('.nestedrepeater').DataTable()
});
```

However, there is still a problem. The jquery functionalities won't work inside the nested repeater, nesting, search etc...

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to nested Table.

`<table id="tblArquivoLocalizacoes" class="table nestedDT table-bordered table-hover dataTable">`

Then initialize.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#tblArquivo').DataTable();
     $('.nestedDT').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: Hi I did this, however the jquery search function, pagination etc won't work on the child tables.

Comment: did you check console for any error? can you try it without using repeater for inner datatable , just to debug?